# How to map relationship between these entities -Coredata iOS

Tags: ios, database, core-data, entity-relationship

I have two entities Account and Transaction. Following conditions are applicable for the db.

1. Each Account has different transactions
      `allTransactions` has to many relationship with `Transaction` table
2. Each transaction related to one account (Debited from `Account`/ Credited To `Account`), `accounts` has to one relationship with `Account` Table.
3. Amount can be transferred between the accounts. (`Transaction`)

Problem: How can i relate the transaction table with `Account` Table for the above (point 3) condition

My Coredata Structure

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are transferring an amount from one account to another account, you need references to *two* accounts.

```
Transaction 
  - fromAccount <<--> Account
  - toAccount   <<--> Account
```

On the Account side you will need two inverse relationships.

```
Account
  - outgoing <--->> Transaction
  - incoming <--->> Transaction
```

So you do not need the property `accounts`. (It is also confusing to name a to-one relationship in the plural.) Similarly, you will not need `allTransactions`.